# Python Loops: Extra Print?

Tags: python, function, loops, printing, for-loop

Im doing a back of the book exercise in Python Programming: An Intro to Comp Sci:

```
for i in [1,3,5,7,9]:
    print(i, ":", i**3)
print(i)
```

this prints out

```
1:1
3:27
5:125
7:343
9:729
9
```

My questions is why does it print the extra 9? Wouldn't the last loop print be 9:729 ?
It has to be something to do with the

```
print(i, ":", i**3)
```

because if I just put in:

```
for i in [1,3,5,7,9]:
   print(i)
```

It just prints

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

Thanks in advance as I have nobody else to help me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python for loops, the "body" of the loop is indented.

So, in your case, `print(i, ":", i**3)` is the "body". It will print `i, ":", i**3` for each value of `i`, starting at 1 and ending at 9.

As the loop executes, it changes the value of `i` to the next item in the list.

Once the loop terminates, it continues to the next line of code, which is completely independent of the for-loop. So, you have a single command after the for-loop, which is `print(i)`. Since `i` was last set at 9, this command basically means `print(9)`.

What you want is:

```
for i in [1,3,5,7,9]:
    print(i, ":", i**3)
```

Comment: Thanks! I get it now! This was the informative answer I was looking for. I think I need to take a break, getting hung up on relatively easy stuff!

Comment: No worries! Keep at it...it's overwhelming at first, but it gets easier

Answer (score 2):

the print(i) at the last line..............

Answer (score 1):

The last value assigned to `i` is 9, so your last line referes to this value assignment that occurred within the loop.  While `9:729` was the last thing printed, it was not the last assignment.

**Edit:**

> why wouldn't it print something like this: 1:1 1 3:27 3 5:125 5 7:343 7 9:729 9?

It would print this if your code were indented and looked like this:

```
for i in [1,3,5,7,9]:
    print(i, ":", i**3)
    print(i)
```

The lack of indentation in the last line causes it to fall outside the for loop.

Comment: For each iteration of the loop, the next value from the list is assigned to `i`.  When the loop terminates, `i` is still a valid variable with the last item from the list assigned to it.  The act of printing (`print(i, ":", i**3)` does not affect the value of `i`.  It does not print like you have in your comment because the last line is not indented.  Indentation in Python is used in determining whether code falls within a loop.

Comment: I appreciate all the help!